# jquery mobile list data filter + virtual keyboard

Tags: jquery-mobile, virtual-keyboard

My jquery mobile application runs on a normal PC with a touchscreen and Windows XP.

I am using a virtual keyboard for input into a textfield, but this doesn't work in combination with the jqm data-filter for lists.
I used Mottie's virtual keyboard and an extension keyboard for Chrome browser.

Live example with Mottie's keyboard: http://jsfiddle.net/6xZXd/

Comment: Your JSFiddle is broken.